# How to set up a db one-to-many relationship in both ways?

Tags: python, django, database

For example, one team has N members, but one member could be in N teams. How can I express this both-way relationship in django? or in Databases in general?

Maybe I'm thinking about it wrong, but on the frontend I want to show all teams for example, or the teams of a player...Don't I need this? Thanks

Comment: Thats called a many-to-many relationship :)

Comment: It's called a Many to Many relationship and in django it's modelled with the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: thanks, gonna dive into that now :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a man-to-many (M:N) relationship and is usually modeled using a linking table. Here is an example:

```
teams
--------
team_id
team_name

persons
--------
person_id
person_name

team_members
---------
person_id
team_id
```

The `team_members` table keeps the relations between teams and persons. A person is a member of a team when a corresponding record with its `person_id` and the `team_id` exists in the `team_members` table. Now the team can hold as many members as necessary (M) and each person can be member of more than one team (N). And here comes the name of the relationship M:N.

Comment: While this is all true, it's unnecessarily confusing for the OP, who just needs a ManyToManyField which creates the linking tables for them.

Comment: Well, the question is also about how it is done in databases in general. The django part is already answered.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to set this answer as correct aswell as the others on commented above....thanks to everyone :)